# What, if any, guarantees are there for when `nalu_process` will be called?

Tags: callback, x264, libx264

In particular, can a call to `x264_encoder_encode` return before every `nalu_process` callback associated to it has returned? Someone in #x264 suggested it's settings-dependent; I'm talking here about the "zerolatency" preset.

If the answer to the above question is *yes*, then how common is it, empirically?

Answer (score 0):

According to BugMaster on #x264 on Freenode, `nalu_process` is always called when inside `x264_encoder_encode`. I'll take his word for it.